# Mongoose not saving data with no error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code

```
      User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (user) {
          return res.status(400).json([{ msg: 'The email address you have entered is already associated with another account.' }]);
        }
        user = new User({
          name: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          password: req.body.password,
          mobile: req.body.mobile
        });
        user.save(function(err) {
          res.json({ token: generateToken(user), user: user });
        });
      });
```

I tried sending a request with postman and I did get a response back with the user object which means there is no err in the save function

```
{
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJleGNlcHRpb25zLnNnIiwic3ViIjoiNTc5NWQ0NzQxYmEzZWQwODE1ZTgzY2NmIiwiaWF0IjoxNDY5NDM3MDQ0LCJleHAiOjE0NzAwNDE4NDR9.2otkcPkJgsXvR8QOHAojDJ5YCxR7Uc2E4ApS77T55F8",
  "user": {
    "__v": 0,
    "created_at": "2016-07-25T08:57:24.612Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-07-25T08:57:24.612Z",
    "name": "Test",
    "email": "Test@hotmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$3UmABiDPeo6iHZ.DFbwOO.1ANpUWQmwr86bYbTmRuFedsbDcE0bbC",
    "mobile": 12345,
    "_id": "5795d4741ba3ed0815e83ccf"
  }
}
```

However there is no entry of this inside my DB. I've check through my database with Robomongo and I'm sure that there is no data. What did I missed out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your arent handling error while saving the collection, replace your `user.save` function with

```
user.save(function(err){
      if(err){
           console.log(err);
           return;
      }

      res.json({ token: generateToken(user), user: user });
});
```

By this you will be able to track whether the data is saved or not and what can be the associated error.

Comment: Thanks. I had a username field duplicate key error which does not exists in the schema. Dropped the collection and it works again. Didn't realize I wasn't catching the error.

Answer (score 28):

This doesn't relate to OP's specific situation but for others who are trying unsuccessfully to save after modifying a `Mixed` property of your object, you have to call `markModified(path)` to let Mongoose know that the property has changed.

```
person.anything = { x: [3, 4, { y: "changed" }] }; // anything is 'Mixed' in the schema
person.markModified('anything');
person.save(); // anything will now get saved
```

Check out the 'Mixed' section of the [Mongoose docs here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

Comment: This solved my problem for `save()` not persisting.

Comment: This is what i needed. my save() returns an object with the changes i make, but never persists. `markModfied()` solved my issue.

Comment: This solved my issue as well. I was using nested `Map`s as opposed to `Mixed`. I was even checking `isModified`, which was returning `true`, and `save` wasn't giving any errors, but it still wouldn't persist. Using `markModified` was the only way to get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

I know this sounds stupid, but Mongoose uses collection name in plural so

```
mongoose.model('User' ...
```

saves to users collection. I lost some hours before I **refreshed the mongoDB client** and realized that all my documents were in 'users' not in 'user'.

Comment: wow, they also pluralize under the hood.  'person' -> 'people'.  I have ran into so many issues with this library, I will never use it outside being paid to.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this issue, your model's `_id` [SchemaType](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) must be of type `ObjectId`.

Suppose we have a schema and model defined as:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  userID: Number,
  name: String
});

var Users = mongoose.model('collectionName', userSchema);
```

And we want to update the name of the user with `userID` 1234:

```
Users.findOne({userID: 1234}, function(err, user) {
    user.name = "Jane Doe";

    user.save(function(err) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Mongoose will successfully update it by performing:

```
users.update({ _id: ObjectId("anObjectID") }, { '$set': { name: 'Jane Doe' } })
```

If we had set the SchemaType of `_id` to `String` in `userSchema`, it would've done this:

```
users.update({ _id: 'anObjectID' }, { '$set': { name: 'Jane Doe' } })
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is prob Just try this , Change variable name of the user Object

```
User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (user) {
          return res.status(400).json([{ msg: 'The email address you have entered is already associated with another account.' }]);
        }
        newUser = new User({
          name: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          password: req.body.password,
          mobile: req.body.mobile
        });
        newUser.save(function(err,saveUser) {
          res.json({ token: generateToken(saveUser), user: saveUser });
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a error function helped me out!

```
 await user.save(function(err){
  if(err){
       console.log(err);
       return;
  }});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you don't have enough permissions in your database. No matter what solution you're using (in my case it was Atlas), I've set up everything such as "insert, read, delete" etc. except those. They're needed for mongoose to browse collections, create new etc.

Without it, got the same symptoms. The result with real (!) data but no reflection in the database. So my advice, check permissions.

[image]